# JSP, can it work similar to yield, layout, content_for in Ruby/Rails/Erb

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsp, erb

I am trying to figure out how to most effectively reuse JSP code.
I love the way Rails/erb works in that way ... with yield, layout, content_for

Example:

main_layout.erb.html

```
<html>
  <head><%= yield :head %></head>
  <body><%= yield %></body>
</html>
```

use

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<title>A simple page</title>
<% end %>

<p>Hello, Rails!</p>
```

in controller

```
layout "main_layout"
```

What is the closest I can get to this with JSP (without using extra frameworks)? I know about JSP include but that's not really the same as yield.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: JSP's got nothin' on ERB. It does little more than give you some custom tags and allow you to interact with your model object. You can leverage more power by returning a JSON object and doing JavaScript widgeting, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Another great JSP tag files answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257426/37572

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not familiar with what `yield` and `content_for` provide, but [JSP tag files](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jserverpages3_ch11/index.html) allow you a more robust way to template pages than JSP includes.

**Example:**

layout.tag

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@ attribute name="pageTitle" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>${pageTitle}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:doBody/>
</body>
</html>
```

An individual JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="z" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<z:layout pageTitle="A simple page">
    <p>Hello, JSP!</p>
</z:layout>
```

Just place your layout.tag in the /WEB-INF/tags directory. You can use any available prefix you want, I just used "z" for the example.

Comment: +50000 for showing me a way to do this like ERB without having to use Tiles.

Comment: that's exactly what I need, I didn't want to use tiles

Comment: I'm getting {$pageTitle} in the title tag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The $ needs to be outside of the braces for EL. `${pageTitle}`, not `{$pageTitle}`.

Answer (score 0):

While you mentioned wanting no frameworks on top of stock jsp, the [Layout](http://stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Layout+Reuse) functionality of the [Stripes Framework](http://stripesframework.org) does pretty much exactly what you're asking for.