# Check if JSP fragment has been set

Tags: jsp

I came across the following tutorial [JSP tricks to make templating easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier) for using JSP to create page templates (how have I missed this for so long?!?).  However, after doing some searching, I cannot seem to figure out how (or if it is possible) to check if a JSP fragment has been set.

**Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:**

I have a template named `default.tag`.  It has 2 JSP attributes defined as follows:

```
<%@attribute name="title" fragment="true" required="true" %>
<%@attribute name="heading" fragment="true" %>
```

Then in the code of the page, I have the `<title>` element of the page set to `<jsp:invoke fragment="title" />`.  Then later down the page, I have the following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${true}">
        <jsp:invoke fragment="heading" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <jsp:invoke fragment="title" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Where I have `<c:when test="${true}">`, I want to be able to check if the `heading` fragment has been set in order to display it, but if not, then default to the `title` fragment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After doing some more messing around, I'm going to answer my own question.  It turns out that the name given to the `attribute` actually becomes a variable as well.  Therefore, I can do the following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty heading}">
        <jsp:invoke fragment="heading" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <jsp:invoke fragment="title" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

That was all I needed to do.  Seems like I was just trying to make it harder than it needed to be!

Comment: one mention, do not use `header` as name, if fragment is not provided, then attribute will hold request headers