# Using JSP files to fill-in the parts of HTML (similar to Django's template system)

Tags: jsp, django-templates

Is it possible to include a JSP file (e.g. `base_html.jsp`) from a custom JSP file (e.g. `page.jsp`) and fill-in the parts? What I mean is I'd like to be able to define a HTML structure in a `base_html.jsp` and then fill-in some parts such as page title and some element's body.

This is similar to Django's template system, where you can create a block with an identifier, so that you can fill-in that block in other templates.

Here's a sample of what I want to do, but in Django's template language:

base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--some generic stuff-->
</head>
    <body>
        <!--more stuff-->
        <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!--more stuff-->
    </body>
</html>
```

page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!--lots of content and some dynamic stuff going on here-->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP tricks to make templating easier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)

Comment: By the way, with JSP's successor Facelets, it's much easier to create compositions like that.

Answer (score 0):

JSP files get the data from request, session, or application attributes. If the attributes are stored where the included JSP expects to find them, they will be displayed without any problem:

For example:

page.jsp:

```
<c:set var="pageTitle" value="Hello world" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="/base_html.jsp"/>
```

base_html.jsp:

```
<h1><c:out value="${pageTitle}"/></h1>
```

Comment: I want to provide more than just a short string but a huge chunk of HTML content. I've edited the question to add the sample of what is possible in Django's template system.

Comment: Then look for a templating system like Apache Tiles, or SiteMesh, or other templating tags coming with various MVC frameworks (Stripes has such tags, for example).

Comment: Can't do that, we are forced to use (pure) JSP at university. It's nothing fancy, we just have to create a website with JSP. But I don't want to copy-paste my HTML structure into every single JSP file.