# What is the best way to create JSP layout template?

Tags: jsp

I'm wondering is there a neat way to create a layout jsp and reuse it on similar jsp pages, something like asp.net master pages.

I googled it, some people say use templates https://web.archive.org/web/20111029180218/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates
that uses custom JSP tags. It says to put a tag like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/template.tld' prefix='template' %>
```

but I get error.

I would be glad to help me know the best way.

What I need is to split page's layout into parts like content, header, and set this parts in the page that uses the layout template, exactly like asp.net master page.

Comment: possible solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2000/jw-0915-jspweb.html    i dont know the best way

Comment: thanks I think the first link is great
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier

Comment: This can also be achieved with jsp:include. Chad Darby explains well here in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWbYj0qoNHo