# how to display web page template in the jsp?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm new to web application. 
Currently i have designed 5 jsp pages, which helps my purpose.
Each jsp file, i have created a table which contains caption and name of the project.

Is there a way to design this banner separately and include in all my webpages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may look it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create JSP layout template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529963/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-jsp-layout-template)