# Make sure to have only single html & body tag per view in Struts 2 tiles use

Tags: java, html, struts2, tiles

I am a newbie and recently joined as a fresher. My TL asked me to take care of no view should have multiple html and body tags.
Entire application is developed using struts 2 tiling and all views are extending to baselayout like below:

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/pages/common/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="XYZ - Base Layout" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/common/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/common/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="display.home.page" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="XYZ - Home" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/home/displayHomePage.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/common/homeHeader.jsp" />
</definition>
```

As of now there are separate html & body tags in each JSp, making each view(having multiple tiles) to have multiple html & body tags
I am not sure how to achieve this. Have following queries:

1. Shall I take an open tag in header and an corresponding closing in
   footer for each separate view?
2. Shall I keep html & body opening and closing tags in baseLayout.jsp only and
   should remove both tags from all of my other JSP's like below:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta charset="UTF-8">
> <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /> </title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>  <div class="gridContainer clearfix"> 
>   <!--Header-->
>    <div id="header"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /></div>
>   <!--Content-->
>    <div class="content-area">
>      <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></div>
>     </div>
>  </div>
>     <!--Footer-->
>      <div id="footer"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /></div>
>       <input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no"><!--Footer End--> 
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [which one of these is the better approach of using tiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465220/which-one-of-these-is-the-better-approach-of-using-tiles)

Answer (score 1):

you better go with the 2nd option. As keeping html and body tags in each jsp can lead to many other problems. I faced such a problem. So keep html head body opening and closing tags in baselayout.jsp only. and whatever other jsps u have, keep only the required tags there.
refer [struts 2 jquery plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331967/struts-2-jquery-plugin-not-working). Thats wht i faced. I m also s fresher like u. :)