# How to use custom properties with Sitemesh 3

Tags: jsp, templates, sitemesh

Given a simple template JSP for rendering by Sitemesh 3:

```
<%@include file="../jsp_inc/taglibs.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value="/css/global.css" />' >
</head>
<body>
<h1>[HEADING]</h1>
<div>
    <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
</div>
</body>
```

That template works as expected, inserting the content of the JSP  element into the template.

As you might expect from the above, I want to be able to insert a value set in the JSP (eg. h1 element) into the appropriate  element in my template.

I tried:

```
<sitemesh:getProperty property="page.heading"></sitemesh:getProperty>
```

in the template/decorator and:

```
<content tag="heading"></content>
```

In the JSP, per another question on SO but I think that may have been referring to Sitemesh 2. I am using Sitemesh 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Incidentally this post changed my life http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier  I see no reason to ever use SiteMesh again, jsp tags are thoroughly better

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if you're still using Sitemesh 3, but I was checking it out and after trolling through the source code found that you have configure the builder.

I'm using the [Java based configuration](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh3/Configuring+SiteMesh+3) and created my own subclass that adds a tag processing rule bundle that supports Sitemesh 2 style content blocks:

```
public class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
    @Override
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        builder.addTagRuleBundle(new Sm2TagRuleBundle());
    }
}
```

Via XML configuration in sitemesh3.xml:

```xml
<sitemesh>
    <content-processor>
        <tag-rule-bundle class="org.sitemesh.content.tagrules.html.Sm2TagRuleBundle" />
    </content-processor>
    <!-- Your mappings go here -->
    <mapping ... />
</sitemesh>
```

Doing this allows you to use content tags like:

```
<content tag="heading"></content>
```

In the decorator/template page use a `sitemesh:write` tag instead of `sitemesh:getProperty` which doesn't exist anymore:

```
<sitemesh:write property="page.heading"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phuong LeCong. This worked for me. I wonder why this answer is not up-voted/accepted.