# Which template method in JSP/Servlet is better

Tags: java, jsp, templates

Which template method is more common?

a) Generating 2 static files header.jsp, footer.jsp, few dynamic files, eg. index.jsp, content.jsp and using `<jsp-config>` so whenever servlet forwards header and footer are appended.

### web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
      <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/header.jspf</include-prelude>
      <include-coda>/WEB-INF/footer.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

### Servlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/index")
    // ...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // do work
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Pros:

- special attributes are not needed

Cros:

- code is separated

b) Generating 1 static file mainpage.jsp, few dynamic files and using `<jsp:include page='${pageUrl}'>` so whenever servlet forwards needs to add attribute with site-content url

### Servlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/index")
// ...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // do work
    request.setAttribute("pageUrl", "index.jsp");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/mainpage.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

### mainpage.jsp

```
<%@ page ... #>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <jsp:include page='${pageUrl}'>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@ page ... %>
content
```

Pros:

- code is organised

Cros:

- special attribute is needed

c) ?

Comment: If you're using JSF, it already provides template system but you should use Facelets for that. If not, use a theme system like freemarker.

Comment: See [jsp tricks to make templating easier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)