# can we use HTML template in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring framework. I have built simple web application from JSP. I have used by making template in HTML using CSS and Javascript. Now i want to make same project in Spring so Can i implement my template in spring framework or not? If it is possible how to implement it.

Comment: What kind of template (Java or JavaScript)? Are you planning on using jsp/jstl/something else?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to what exactly you are asking for. Please provide more information about a specific problem you are having implementing your project. If you are simply asking if you can have HTML and CSS in Spring projects, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC can use a variety of view technologies, such as Freemarker, Velocity, Thymeleaf, and Plain Old JSPs.

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think you are referring to having one Template file, with multiple views that use that Template. Is that correct?

To do so there are a few methods.

One is to include a header/footer on each view using jsp:include. See [JSP tricks to make templating easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)

Another option is to use [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/pattern.html), which uses the Composite View Pattern.

Another option is to use [SiteMesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home), which uses the Decorator Pattern.

The first option is probably the easiest for a simple site.