# Randomly getting Unterminated tag error

Tags: jsp

I haven't found any question with the same problem that I have.

With:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/template" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="modal" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/modal" %>

<template:page pageTitle="${pageTitle}">
  <jsp:attribute name="modal">modal content</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>body content</jsp:body>  
</template:page>
```

my page renders fine. But just by swaping the 2 lines:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/template" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="modal" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/modal" %>

<template:page pageTitle="${pageTitle}">
  <jsp:body>body content</jsp:body>  
  <jsp:attribute name="modal">modal content</jsp:attribute>
</template:page>
```

the page **randomly** sometimes renders fine and sometimes give me the error:

`HTTP Status 500 - /WEB-INF/views/desktop/pages/account/accountLoginPage.jsp (line: 9, column: 2) Unterminated &lt;template:page tag`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post whole error

Comment: What's in `${pageTitle}`?

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli The whole error is: *HTTP Status 500 - /WEB-INF/views/desktop/pages/account/accountLoginPage.jsp (line: 9, column: 2) Unterminated &lt;template:page tag*.

Comment: @developerwjk ${pageTitle} contains a String with the page title. Basically, "Login", "Home", etc

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli `<jsp:attribute name="modal">modal content</jsp:attribute>` is in line 9 when I get the error (I've removed all code except that that I've actually shown in the question, and the error still exists)

Comment: The downvoter mind to say the reason?