# What is the best practice for layout of jsp page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jsp-fragments

Simple example: i have a page with header, footer and left menu. This modules viewing always. In header i am use dynamic information for count of users. I am create jspf files for header, for footer and left menu and include it to main page. I have Spring controllers and always need include to model variable for calculation of users. Maybe you know how it's do more grateful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to include a model among multiple controllers, then use a @ControllerAdvice with a @ModelAttribute method

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDataAdvice {

  @Autowired
  private FooService fooService;

  @ModelAttribute("foo")
  Foo getFoo(){
        return fooService.find(...);
  }  
}
```

I like SiteMesh for my layouts. It's pretty easy to use. http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Start+Using+SiteMesh+in+10+Minutes

You can also use JSP Tag Files. [JSP tricks to make templating easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)