# No tag defined in tag library imported with prefix

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, custom-tags

I am working with Java EE 7 in Intellij IDEA and trying to create and use a custom .tag file. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257426/4545369) answer and created a wrapper.tag file in WEB-INF/tags :

```
<%@tag description="Simple Wrapper Tag" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html><body>
  <jsp:doBody/>
</body></html>
```

And i have created a .jsp file in my web directory:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:wrapper>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</t:wrapper>
```

But when loading the page I always one of two following errors:

- No tag "wrapper" defined in tag library imported with prefix "t"
- lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.temptest_jsp

Note that my jsp file is called temptest.jsp.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the files in the folder tags?

Comment: @CarlosLaspina They are .tag files. So far I only have wrapper.tag

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to check, I was also facing the same problem

1. `<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="tag" %>` add '/' after tags
2. In the `tagdir` path there should be no spelling mistakes, I had forgot to add 's' to `tags` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've also met this problem before. Turn out, my tags folder in out/artifacts/WEB-INF wasn't updated after I renamed the folder. You may want to check that.

I'm not good at Java. In fact, I'm a C# dev. My solution is to manually rename the folder. There must be a way that we can update these actions automatically that I haven't known. :)

[image: The reference folder]