# How to reuse jsp file with html insertion in it?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a jsp file, like template of a page with header, footer, but without body, so in other jsp file i want to use this template and **insert html body into it**. So i need to create a lot of pages using this template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSP tricks to make templating easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is re-using the jsp pages across multiple other pages in application then,

Considering static header and footer pages, you can use below code to re-use the header and footer template JSP pages in your multiple pages.

See **NewPage.jsp** sample code below

```
<%@ include file="Header.jsp" %> 

<%-- Your html body will come here --%> 

<%@ include file="Footer.jsp" %>
```

If it does not answer your question then please give more details about your question.