# How do you manage static contents/pages with gwt?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gwt

I have been using Django with GAE/Python and recently I have been considering switching to GAE/J and GWT.  My questions are

1) Is there a way to do hierarchical templating similar to the Django template system?

2) How do you manage static contents with/along with GWT in general?

I have been digging around quite a bit but I haven't been able to find something satisfactory.  Here's a summary of the possible solution (I don't know if my conclusion of them are accurate though since I am not that familar with java tech.)

a) Use various java frameworks/template engine (Spring, FreeMarker, StringTemplate, Velocity, etc) but is it possible to mix use these with GWT?

b) Use Django with Jyphon... but then I am not really using GWT+servlet any more right? (And lose things like GWT RPC?)

c) Use JSP straight ... but there doesn't seem to be hierarchical template.  As I type this I did some search and some have referenced Tile (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490390/jsp-template-inheritance) does that work well with GWT?

d) Use GWT UiBinder.  Base on the description of the dev guide, this seems to be exactly what I needed but then the examples I see are small and it seems to be best suited for layout of widget as oppose to a page.  And using UiBinder means that the page is still js generated right? (not crawlable, etc?)

Again, some of the conclusion above could be wrong since I am new to the server side java tech.  Please correct me if they are inaccurate.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085898/choosing-java-vs-python-on-google-app-engine had a lot of relevant information for me.  One particular note was that GWT client could be used with Python back end.

Answer (score 0):

For Templating try Sitemesh -- very easy to setup and use. I'm currently running an application on GAE with Spring/Sitemesh/GWT. The only reason I chose to use java is that GWT-RPC is written for it. The biggest problem with using Java on GAE is the cold-start issue: [read this post](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2456) This actually is a huge obstacle, so think twice before moving to Java.

Comment: Well, Spring is very heavy weight for cold starting on GAE, so if you're going with Java, you might considering using something else (Guice for example).

Comment: I think this cold start issue may not be limited to GAE/J.  I have experience similar lag in GAE/Python although not as severe (around 2~3 sec.)  In the python case, it's the spin up of my Django framework.

Comment: It doesn't matter which framework you use, as long as it's Java, the cold-start time is going to be unacceptable. Even a 5 second wait is enough to turn users away, so the best approach, for now, is to use python. The post that I linked discusses the issue, including the future of 'reserved' instances and 'warm-up hooks'.

Comment: BTW, at the present time, I've setup my application in such a way that the first page that a user would access is a static page, which fires an async call to the backend to kickstart the application (I'm also using a cron job to do the same, if the user accesses the application from a search result, which would take him to the non-static content). But this is a hack, and the reason I'm fine with it is that I'm planning on rolling out the full-fledged application early next year -- by that time I'm hoping that the issue is resolved, or at least improved.